# Play sound on animation state exit

Tags: unity, c#

I'm trying to figure out how to play a sound effect when a game object leaves a particular state and goes into another. For simplicity, let's just say I want a sound effect to play when the animation for an object transitions from state A to state B, but not the other way around and not for other states. How would I achieve this? I've found information related to playing sound effects when entering a state, but not when exiting from one particular state to another.

To be more specific, I tried implementing this code as a behavior on State A exit:

```
override public void OnStateExit(Animator animator, AnimatorStateInfo stateInfo, int layerIndex)
    {
        GameObject self = animator.gameObject;
        MyScript myScript = self.GetComponent<MyScript>();
        myScript.PlaySFX();
    }
```

But since state A is accessible from any state, I think it is constantly entering state A from itself over and over again. I say this because the sound effect plays repeatedly whenever I am in state A.

Comment: Have you tried using [`StateMachineBehaviour.OnStateExit`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/StateMachineBehaviour.OnStateExit.html)?

Comment: I considered this, but I can't seem to figure out how to do this properly.

Comment: What did you try, and what aspect do you need help with?

Answer (score 0):

> But since state A is accessible from any state, I think it is constantly entering state A from itself over and over again. I say this because the sound effect plays repeatedly whenever I am in state A.

Check `Can Transition To Self` in the inspector.

[image]

Comment: It sounds more like he would want to _uncheck_ that option, since he doesn't want the sound effect to keep playing over and over.